# How to save and update at the same time with laravel and vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm having a problem that I couldn't find an answer in anywhere yet.
I'm writing an app with PHP(Laravel) in the backend and VueJs in the frontend.
I've managed to do the entire application with no much problem but now, I have to save and update one table at the same time, i'll explain following the code.

**Scenario Update**

I'm writing a maintenance control, i have to input records of maintenances in a table so, there are some maintenances that are made periodically and i'm supposed to warn when the next maintenance is comming, that's why i need to POST and Put at the same time.
I can't send a single request from vue to laravel because i'm using routes and, if it goes with the POST method, i get method not allowed error, as you can see in the controller's function, i already tried to use a single request.

Here's the routes that i'm using in a main vue file:

```
<b-tab title="Cadastro de Manutenções">
                    <manutencao-cadastro
                        rotacadadd="manutencao/cadastro/"
                        rotamaquina="manutencao/cadastro/autcomp"
                        rotatipoautcomp="manutencao/cadastro/axios-tipo"
                        rotanomecolaborador="manutencao/cadastro/nomeColaborador"
                        rotacadsalvar="manutencao/cadastro/salvarManutencao"
                        rotacadatualizar="manutencao/cadastro/updateManute"
                        rotacaddel="manutencao/cadastro/deleteManute"
                        rotaatualizacadastro="manutencao/cadastro/atualizaCad"
                    />
                </b-tab>
```

Here's my function to save/update on vue:

```
save(){
            const method = this.maintenance.id ? 'put' : 'post'
            const id = this.maintenance.id ? `/${this.maintenance.id}` : ''
            const url = this.maintenance.id ? this.rotacadatualizar : this.rotacadsalvar
            axios[method](`${url}${id}`, this.maintenance)
                .then(() => {
                    this.reset()
                }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err)
            });
    }
```

As you can see, this function saves or updates depending on the case, working normally.

This is my function at the backend:

```
public function saveMaintenance(Request $request)
{

    $maquina = $this->ManutencaoMaquinasM
        ->where('descricao', $request->maquina)
        ->first();

    $tecnico = $this->ColaboradorM
        ->where('nomecolaborador', $request->tecnico)
        ->first();

    $manutencao = $this->TecManutencaoTipoM
        ->where('manutencao', $request->manutencao)
        ->first();

    $dia = '';

    $data = $this->TecManutencaoCadastroM->join('manutencao_maquinas', 'tec_manutencao_cadastros.maqId', 'manutencao_maquinas.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('max(tec_manutencao_cadastros.data) as date'))
        ->where('manutencaoId', $manutencao->id)
        ->where('manutencao_maquinas.descricao', $request->maquina)
        ->get();

    foreach ($data as $dat) {
        $dia = $dat->date;
    }

    try{
        \DB::beginTransaction();
        $input = $request->all();

        $maintenance = new TecManutencaoCadastro();
        $maintenance->maqId = $maquina->id;
        $maintenance->tipoId = $input['tipo'];
        $maintenance->manutencaoId = $manutencao->id;
        $maintenance->tecnicoId = $tecnico->id;
        $maintenance->data = $input['data'];
        $maintenance->tempo = $input['tempo'];
        $maintenance->obs = $input['obs'];
        $maintenance->save();

        /* $atualizar = $this->TecManutencaoCadastroM
            ->where('madIq', $maquina->id)
            ->where('manutencaoId', $manutencao->id)
            ->where('data', $dia)
            ->update(array('atendido' => 's')); */

        //\Log::info($maintenance);

        \DB::commit();

        return response()->json('salvo', 200);

    } catch (\Exception $e){
        \DB::rollback();
        return response()->json($e.'erro', 422);
    }
}
```

Also working fine when I have to save the data.
The commented block works in laravel but with in vue, it doesn't.

This is the function to update:

```
public function updateMaintenance(Request $request)
{
    $maquina = $this->ManutencaoMaquinasM
        ->where('descricao', $request->maquina)
        ->first();

    $tecnico = $this->ColaboradorM
        ->where('nomecolaborador', $request->tecnico)
        ->first();

    $manutencao = $this->TecManutencaoTipoM
        ->where('manutencao', $request->manutencao)
        ->first();

    try{
        \DB::beginTransaction();

        $tipo = $this->TecManutencaoCadastroM->where('id', '=', $request->id)
            ->update(
                array(
                    'maqId' => $maquina->id,
                    'tipoId' => $request->tipo,
                    'manutencaoId' => $manutencao->id,
                    'tecnicoId' => $tecnico->id,
                    'data' => $request->data,
                    'tempo' => $request->tempo,
                    'obs' => $request->obs
                )
            );


        \DB::commit();

        return response()->json('salvo', 200);

    } catch (\Exception $e){
        \DB::rollback();
        return response()->json($e.'erro', 422);
    }
}
```

Working as suposed to do.

My problem is, I'm trying to save some new data in the table and update another row in the same table, in the same time, but as you can see in the vue method, when I save, the path points to POST and when I update, the path points to PUT, I guess that's why i'm not able to do this action.
Is that a way for me to do this?
I'm new on vue and didn't find anything that could help me.
Can anyone point me some directions please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like this should be 2 separate requests: 1x POST and 1x PUT. Any reason why you don't do 2 requests?

Comment: FYI - there's nothing stopping you from calling the other function directly from the first one. But this feels hacky to me.

Comment: Hi @waterloomatt, thanks for responding, in this particular case, i need to make a POST and a PUT request at the same time, this is the scenario, you make maintenance in one machine and have the value 'n' in one column,  when you make the same maintenance in the same machine again, the new record will have this 'n' value and the old record will update to 's' value, so when i save the second record, the oldest have to update to 's'.

Comment: @waterloomatt, i actually think the same about calling a function directly from the other but i'm getting `app.js:279 PUT http://localhost:8000/ 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`, with another php function, but it seems hacky to me as well

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add in the scenario you described + any additional details you think are relevant? Sounds like this could be a good candidate for a database trigger or simply a longer workflow initiated by a single request.

Comment: @waterloomatt, i'm trying not to use triggers or anything in the database, only using the back and frontend

Comment: @waterloomatt, what information do you think that can be useful?

Comment: I just meant to include your use case/scenario as it is important to understand your process in order to make a good recommendation. If I was you, I would send a single request from Vue. Then, in the PHP that handles that method, check to see if that specific maintenance has been performed before. If it has, update the row and set the value to `s`. After that, do the insert of the new row with the value of `n`. Do both of these in the same method and wrap them in a transaction.

Comment: Hi @waterloomatt, thanks for helping me and sorry for the late answer, i already try to use a single request from vue to laravel but didn't work as in laravel, now i'm trying your other ideia, about two functions, still have no success, if you have any idea on how to make this work, ll'be grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it you have 2 options. Either initiate 2 separate requests (at the same time) OR send a single request and let PHP figure out how to handle both the insert and the update.

*Not sure what the difference between `TecManutencaoCadastro`  and `TecManutencaoCadastroM` is so I just copied/pasted it from your example.*

**Scenario 1: Send 2 requests**

Keep both your `saveMaintenance` and `updateMaintenance` PHP methods, and initiate a single request for each one. Ex. [Axios-Make multiple request at once (vue.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540079/axios-make-multiple-request-at-once-vue-js)

```
axios.all([
    this.make_post_request(),
    this.make_put_request()
])
...
make_post_request() {
    return axios.post('...url...', { params: 'example' })
},
make_put_request() {
    return axios.put('...url...', { params: 'example' })
}
...
```

**Scenario 2: Make a single (post) request**

Pass all your data along with the request and let PHP determine what to do with it. This scenario just expands the `post` (insert) functionality to handle your specific use-case of also updating the prior maintenance record *if it exists*.

```
save(){
    axios['post'](`...url...`, this.maintenance)
        .then(() => {
            ...
        })
    );
}
```

`PHP`

```
public function saveMaintenance(Request $request)
{
    // Begin transaction

    // The request has an `id` parameter so do the update to set the status to `s`.
    if ($request->has('id')) {
        $tipo = $this->TecManutencaoCadastroM->where('id', '=', $request->id)
            ->update(
                ...
            );                
    }

    // Finally, create the new maintenance row with value `n`.
    $maintenance = new TecManutencaoCadastro();
    ...
    $maintenance->save();

    // Commit transaction
}
```

*You should keep `updateMaintenance` for when you want to actually issue a `put` request to update a maintenance record.*

Comment: Hi @waterloomatt, thanks for answering, i've tried the Scenario 2 before and didn't work for me, getting method not allowed error, i'l try the Scenario 1 and come back with the results.

Comment: Hi @waterloomatt, i've tried scenario 1 and, it saves normally but i have method not allowed error on PUT, change a lot of things and didn't work at all. I think that i'll have to pass some parameter in route, this time is different from the update that i did before, i'll find a way, somehow, thanks for all the help so far...

Comment: finally i could make the post and put request together, a little different but, with your idea.
Thanks a lot.